# TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader Servlet ClassNotFoundException

Tags: spring, tomcat, servlets, aop

I using Tomcat 6 as the App Server for my web application which uses the AOP to inject DAO into servlet.

```
Dec 31, 2012 5:21:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\SnapAPI\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32\eclipse;;.
Dec 31, 2012 5:21:02 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:BISDAO' did not find a matching property.
Dec 31, 2012 5:21:02 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context/Loader} Setting property 'useSystemClassLoaderAsParent' to 'false' did not find a matching property.
Dec 31, 2012 5:21:02 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Dec 31, 2012 5:21:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 288 ms
Dec 31, 2012 5:21:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Dec 31, 2012 5:21:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
Dec 31, 2012 5:21:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
17:21:02,477  INFO ContextLoader:272 - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
17:21:02,571  INFO XmlWebApplicationContext:510 - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Dec 31 17:21:02 SGT 2012]; root of context hierarchy
17:21:02,635  INFO XmlBeanDefinitionReader:315 - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
17:21:02,967  INFO DefaultContextLoadTimeWeaver:89 - Using a reflective load-time weaver for class loader: org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader
17:21:03,614  INFO DefaultListableBeanFactory:577 - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@188c838: defining beans [org.springframework.context.config.internalBeanConfigurerAspect,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,genericDAOImpl,org.springframework.context.weaving.AspectJWeavingEnabler#0,loadTimeWeaver,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.cache.annotation.AnnotationCacheOperationSource#0,org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor#0,org.springframework.cache.config.internalCacheAdvisor,org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0,dataSource,jdbcTemplate,genericDaoImpl,transactionManager,ehcache,cacheManager,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
17:21:03,944  INFO EhCacheManagerFactoryBean:100 - Initializing EHCache CacheManager
17:21:04,263  INFO MLog:80 - MLog clients using log4j logging.
17:21:04,330  INFO C3P0Registry:204 - Initializing c3p0-0.9.1.2 [built 21-May-2007 15:04:56; debug? true; trace: 10]
17:21:04,471  INFO ContextLoader:301 - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1993 ms
Dec 31, 2012 5:21:04 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Dec 31, 2012 5:21:04 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Dec 31, 2012 5:21:04 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/11  config=null
Dec 31, 2012 5:21:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2354 ms
Dec 31, 2012 5:21:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet GenericServlet as unavailable
Dec 31, 2012 5:21:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: Error loading org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader
WebappClassLoader
  context: /BISDAO
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@3c0007
 GenericServlet
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: GenericServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1128)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:827)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Dec 31, 2012 5:21:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet GenericServlet
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: GenericServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1128)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:827)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Below is my configuration:

I have put spring-instrument-tomcat-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar into $CATALINA_HOME\lib and have context.xml inside my META-INF folder.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context path="/BISDAO">
    <Loader loaderClass="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader" />
</Context>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <!-- Enable @Required @Autowired @PreDestroy @PostConstruct @Resource -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Scan class file in class path for annotated component -> @Component, @Repository, @Service, and @Controller  -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.breeze.bis.core.service.jdbcTemplate" />

    <!-- Enable load time weaving for @Configurable -->
    <context:load-time-weaver aspectj-weaving="autodetect" />

    <!--  -->
    <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="false" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <!-- ==================================================================================================== -->

    <!-- Alternate method to enable @Autowired -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vbossdb" />
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="user" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <constructor-arg type="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="dataSource"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="genericDaoImpl" class="com.breeze.bis.core.service.jdbcTemplate.GenericDAOImpl">
        <property name="jdbcDao" ref="jdbcTemplate"></property> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property> 
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Servlet.java

```
@Configurable
public class GenericServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Autowired
    GenericDAO dao;
}
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: show us the web.xml, something is probably missing inthere or a typo, or a wrong servlet declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define servlet class using custom package in web.xml

Answer (score 0):

Your servlet shouldn't be in the default package. Move it into a proper package, and it'll probably work.

Comment: No, the GenericServlet is not in default pacakge.

Comment: That stack trace sure looks like it's trying to load GenericServlet with no package, so you might double check that anywhere you refer to the servlet by name, it's done correctly.

Comment: I'm confirm that the GenericServlet is not in default package.

Comment: It seems like the application uses the default class loader when loading the GenericServlet in default package but it uses the TomInstrumentClassLoader when loading at run time. I tried put GenericServlet.class in default package and it complaint NoClassDefFoundException by TomInstrumentClassLoader.